# JacksonJsonSupport trait causes a NoSuchMethodError for initialize()

Tags: scala, jackson, scalatra

I'm going through the [Scalatra "Handling JSON" tutorial](http://www.scalatra.org/2.4/guides/formats/json.html) for Scalatra 2.4, and I'm getting a "NoSuchMethodError":

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.scalatra.json.JacksonJsonSupport$class.initialize(Lorg/scalatra/json/JacksonJsonSupport;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at com.tutorial.FlowersController.initialize(FlowersController.scala:8)
    at com.tutorial.FlowersController.initialize(FlowersController.scala:8)
    at org.scalatra.ScalatraServlet$class.init(ScalatraServlet.scala:123)
    at com.tutorial.FlowersController.init(FlowersController.scala:8)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:862)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.main(Runner.java:557)
```

I added the "with JacksonJsonSupport", along with the "protected implicit lazy val jsonFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats" just after the controller signature.  I have the two imports at the top, import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, Formats} and import org.scalatra.json._

And for completeness, my ScalatraBootstrap has no package declaration, and is as follows:

```
import com.tutorial._
import org.scalatra._
import javax.servlet.ServletContext

class ScalatraBootstrap extends LifeCycle {
  override def init(context: ServletContext) {
    context.mount(new FlowersController, "/*")
  }
}
```

I added "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-json" % ScalatraVersion, and "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.3.0", to build.scala and restarted sbt.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with an "sbt clean".  The tutorial suggests just restarting sbt to download the new jars, and going through it again, it worked fine, but my initial attempt was apparently not quite right.  The only difference I can think of, was that I was running the initial attempt in a Docker container, and maybe something wasn't perfect with that.

Comment: Didn't work for me...this is a strange bug that's hard to track down. It doesn't seem to be a common issue either.